# Is there an alternativ way to get infos (user, call quality) from Ms Teams Calls without Graph Api Call Records "before ending the call"?

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

The Standard way for Analyzing Call Quality is  subscribe to Call Records Notification and implement an webhook for doing such stuff.

Then the way is after a Call has ended, MS writes the Call details to their DB and the subscription to the webhook, with further REST-Calls using  graph api call the complete Call Record details(, start , end , participants, quality,..) could be requested an analysed.

The problem is e.g. if an user with an "always on pc" left office, the call will not ended so so no notification is sended.

Is there a way to get Call Infos from the other(s) user(s), which left the call on an this pseudo-active Call session behalf one missing user-logout?

Is there an Ms Teams or (old skype for business) Api which can request user calls on a different way?

Comment: please have a look into this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/cqd-power-bi-query-templates

Comment: Can you please share any online tutorial on how to implement the standard way you just describe? I have a requirement where we need to bypass powerbi but to show Call Quality data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your valuable suggestion and for directing in the right direction, @Sayali-MSFT.

The Microsoft Call Quality Dashboard can provide the imported charts as well as live metrics whic are being recorded in Teams. You can add the [CQD Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/cqd-power-bi-connector) to your power BI and select Direct Query after Sign in which will connect live to your data source.

[image]

From there you can extract the reports to logic apps using power BI connector.

[image]

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Use Power BI to analyze CQD data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/cqd-power-bi-query-templates)
2. [Install Power BI Connector to use CQD query templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/cqd-power-bi-connector)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I cannot test it. 
Power BI is no option at this point, but I will keep it in mind.

I hope there is another way so I will wait 2 weeks I think.
If there is no other answer with an alternative without power bi I will accept this and take it as fact that there is no other known solution for that.